# Histogram from file into array

Tags: java, arrays, histogram

I'm beginner to java and programming basically and I have this problem. I have a file (which contains number from 0 to 10, random) and I need to store it into array B[i], i=0...10 in that way that B[0] contains number of zeros, B[1] number of 1 etc. For example if in my file are three "1" then B[1] = 3. I created this code:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hist {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("in.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
      
        int[] B = new int [10];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int sum = 0;
            while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                int k = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println(i); //control line
                if(i==k){
                    sum=sum+1;
                    B[i] = sum;
                }
            }
        }    
        sc.close();

        for (float x : B) {
            System.out.println(x); //just to see how B looks like
        }
    }
}
```

And as an output I got 20 zeros. So it seems that my code don't iterate through i, but I don't see why.

Answer (score 0):

If the file contains only int values you do not need to read it by line.

```java
int[] B = new int [10];
File file = new File("in.txt");
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file)) { // use try-with-resources to close scanner automatically
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        B[sc.nextInt()]++;
    }
    System.out.println("histogram: " + Arrays.toString(B));
}
```

*Note*: if the numbers in the file are from 0 to 10 *inclusive*, the size of `B` has to be 11.

---

**Update**
If the histogram needs to be presented as 2 arrays where the first array counts values from 1 to 5 inclusive, and the second counts the values from 6 to 10, this can be implemented as simple as:

```java
int[] count1to5 = new int[5];
int[] count6to10 = new int[5];
File file = new File("in.txt");
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        // select the counting array 
        int[] receiver = n > 5 ? count6to10 : count1to5; 

        receiver[(n - 1) % 5]++; // correct index by 1
    }
    System.out.println("histogram 1 to  5: " + Arrays.toString(count1to5));
    System.out.println("histogram 6 to 10: " + Arrays.toString(count6to10));
}
```

---

Similarly, a 2D array may be used to build a histogram for a continuous range of numbers between `min` and `max` divided into subranges of `length` values:

```java
int min = 1;
int max = 10;
int length = 5;
int subranges = (int) Math.ceil((max + 1.0 - min) / length);
int[][] histogram = new int[subranges][length];

File file = new File("in.txt");
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        int n = sc.nextInt() - min; // shift index by min

        // select the subrange
        int[] receiver = histogram[n / length];

        receiver[n % length]++; // correct index inside row
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < histogram.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < histogram[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%2d=%2d  ", i * length + j + min, histogram[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I have another question. If I want to create two arrays (equal size, lets say file contains integers from 1-10) in that way that first array scans through all the file, but cares only for number 1-5 and counts them and second cares only for number 6-10. And I don't want to create big array and then split it, I want two arrays from begging. Is this even possible?

Comment: @Meronam, evrything is possible, please check the update